# What is the contained statement?

Tags: java, jls

[JLS 14.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) used in a description of a rule for unreachable statement some contained statement. To be more specific I'll cite a quote:

> A while statement can complete normally iff at least one of the
>   following is true:
>
> - The while statement is reachable and the condition expression is not a constant expression (§15.28) with value true.
> - There is a reachable break statement that exits the while statement.
>
> The *contained statement* is reachable iff the while statement is
>   reachable and the condition expression is not a constant expression
>   whose value is false.

I'd suspect it's just a while's entire block statement like, for instance, the following:

```
while(true){
    //Something
}
```

That's the contained statement consist of all code enclosed by parentheses, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contained statement would be `\\something` in your example, i.e. the body of the loop. If you read [JLS #14.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.12) the expression *contained statement* is used too and its meaning is possibly clearer in that context.